# Adjust Kivy FileChooser Font Size

Tags: python, kivy

I'm looking for how I can change the font size of all text in a kivy `FileChooserListView` class. I am hoping to do so in pure python if possible. I like that the standard `Label` and `Button` uix classes take `font_size` as an initialize parameter, but it appears the `FileChooserListView` does not. If doing so in pure python isn't an easy approach and there's a good `.kv` file approach, I'd take that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that, but you can fiddle with the `FileListEntry` template that the `FileChooserListView` uses to display the entries. In that template, you can adjust the font sizes used. Here is my attempt at that:

```
Builder.load_string('''
[FileListEntry@FloatLayout+TreeViewNode]:
    locked: False
    entries: []
    path: ctx.path
    # FIXME: is_selected is actually a read_only treeview property. In this
    # case, however, we're doing this because treeview only has single-selection
    # hardcoded in it. The fix to this would be to update treeview to allow
    # multiple selection.
    is_selected: self.path in ctx.controller().selection

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '96dp' if dp(1) > 1 else '48dp'                         # height must be big enough to hold font sized below
    # Don't allow expansion of the ../ node
    is_leaf: not ctx.isdir or ctx.name.endswith('..' + ctx.sep) or self.locked
    on_touch_down: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_touched(self, args[1])
    on_touch_up: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_released(self, args[1])
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint_x: None
        width: root.width - dp(10)
        Label:
            id: filename
            font_size: '48dp'                                  # adjust this font size
            size_hint_x: None
            width: root.width - sz.width                       # this allows filename Label to fill width less size Label
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'left'
            shorten: True
            text: ctx.name
        Label:
            id: sz
            font_size: '48dp'                                  # adjust this font size
            #text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.texture_size[0]                        # this makes the size Label to minimum width
            text: '{}'.format(ctx.get_nice_size())
''')
```

This is based heavily on the `FileListEntry` template in `style.kv`. There are two `font_sizes` that you can adjust, and a `height` for the entry. All three must be coordinated to get a reasonable result.

Comment: This worked well. Wish there was something that was a little simpler, but can't argue with the results. Thank you. :)

Comment: Also I found that by adding `+ dp(18)` to the line `width: self.texture_size[0]` I was able to add a right margin that was kind of lacking. Otherwise looked perfect.